# How to undo all the wpf datagrid changes through a button click

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have binded ObservableCollection to the itemsource of the datagrid, 
Now for each and every operation performed on the datagrid, i am storing the changes in the undo-redo stack, we have two toolbar buttons for undo and redo, so we are supporting undo-redo on click of these buttons, now we have a requirement, where we want to provide a new button which should Undo All grid changes in one click, it should clear the undo stack.
    At present, i am making the call to the business logic to get the original data and reloading the datagrid, as the original data which i have sent to the grid is modified and the changes are accepted. 
      I am trying to see if i can get the original state of the data at the initial load using undo-redo stack with out multiple refreshes in the datagrid [ user should not feel multiple refreshes hapenning]? 
    I can maintain a copy of the data before loading the data to the datagrid, but want to know if i can achieve this by the undo-redo stack or by any functions of observablecollections?

Answer (score 0):

```
...
private myDBDataContext dc = new myDBDataContext(); //context DB
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

//binding the datagrid (WPF) with context db and table
    if (dc.DatabaseExists())
    {
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = dc.myTables;
     }
}
private void Refres_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //call the refresh with "OverwriteCurrentValues" (this is what you need)
    dc.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, dc.myTables);
}
```